# JavaScript closures issue

Tags: javascript

Why this doesn't fire:

```
var counter = function () {

    return function() {
        alert('Fire!');
    }
}

counter();
```

but this does:

```
var counter = function () {

    return function() {
        alert('Fire!');
    }
}

var test = counter(); 
test();
```

It seems like assigning function to a variable makes difference but why?

Comment: You need to call the function after creating it. as you are doing in second code.

Comment: This is not really a closure issue. It's just an issue of using a function object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling the function returned

```
counter()();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a function. You have to call it also.

Answer (score 2):

`count()` returns a function.  It does fire, it just doesn't call the function that it returns.  In the second example, you are returning the inner function, *then* firing it via `test()`.  If you want the examples to be similar, change `test = count()` to `test = counter`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok with your first example, you are assigning

```
function() {
    alert('Fire!');
}
```

to the variable. But aren't asking for it's value. In your second example, you assign the function to the variable as above, then you call are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = function () {
        alert('Fire!');
}

counter();
```

This would fire

Comment: so by `counter()()`, the `alert` would be fired.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
var counter = function () {

    return function() {
        alert('Fire!');
    }
}

counter();
```

you are simple getting a function in return of counter(). It is like calling a function which returns a value and you are not catching it.

You have to catch the return function and then call it as you have done it in second code.